# Can I make a tab show multiple tab panes at once?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if I can make a nav-tab fade in all other tab-panes

```
<li class="nav-item col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Explore">Explore</a>
</li>
</li>

<div class="container col-lg-10 col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Home" class="jumbotron tab-pane fade show active">
            <h3>Our latest Post!</h3>
            <p>Like it? Check out more at explore tab!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Explore" class="jumbotron tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want that when user log's in and is sent to index page, the home link will automatically display every pane in the code, both home and explore.

Comment: No, Bootstrap's Tab component only supports one active tab at a time. Displaying  tab will hide all the others. It sounds like you don't want to use the Bootstrap Tab component.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for my problem then if not tab panes aren't suited for what i am asking?